# How to display picture in DataGridView in C#

Tags: c#, database

I have a book database with some records. Each record have one book details with book name, book link, and book picture path.

I need to display records with book picture in Data Grid View control. I found example how to display picture in Data Grid View but can't find example than to display picture with others fields in each record.

I researched much but I can't find example like this.

Comment: Did you try to add an ImageColumn? What do you mean by 'in other fields'? A diiferent image in each row or in varying columns??? [Examples](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A3152130+datagridview+images)

Comment: i want to show book picture,book name,book link fields in gridview

Comment: See [ask]. Tell us what you want to do, show a [mcve], and tell us what results you get.

Comment: Show us what you have for your DataGridView control definition (aspx or razor page), and the code to populate it. Without that, none of us has enough info to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `DataGridViewImageColumn` to display image.
Refer the below example:

```
dataGridView1.ColumnCount = 3;
dataGridView1.Columns[0].Name = "Product ID";
dataGridView1.Columns[1].Name = "Product Name";
dataGridView1.Columns[2].Name = "Product Price";

string[] row = new string[] { "1", "Product 1", "1000" };
dataGridView1.Rows.Add(row);
row = new string[] { "2", "Product 2", "2000" };
dataGridView1.Rows.Add(row);
row = new string[] { "3", "Product 3", "3000" };
dataGridView1.Rows.Add(row);
row = new string[] { "4", "Product 4", "4000" };
dataGridView1.Rows.Add(row);

DataGridViewImageColumn img = new DataGridViewImageColumn();
Image image = Image.FromFile("Image Path");
img.Image = image;
dataGridView1.Columns.Add(img);
img.HeaderText = "Image";
img.Name = "img";
```